# Order by a SUM with multiple joins in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Solution:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
   SELECT *, SUM(views.times) AS sum
   FROM channel
   RIGHT JOIN video
   ON channel.channel_id = video.channel_id
   LEFT JOIN user
   ON channel.user_id = user.user_id
   LEFT JOIN views
   ON channel.channel_id = views.channel_id
   GROUP BY channel.channel_name
   ORDER BY sum DESC
");
```

I have a query that returns a list of items.

```
function getfrontpage(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('channel');     
    $this->db->join('video', 'channel.channel_id = video.channel_id' , 'right');
    $this->db->join('user', 'channel.user_id = user.user_id');
    $this->db->group_by("channel.channel_name"); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Now i'm trying to order these with the SUM from another table, how can i achieve this?

Here is a picture from that table:
[image: view table]

I want the results to be sorted by the SUM of the total of "times" for each "channel_id"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to run this through `$this->db->query()` instead.

It's nice to fetch simple values through CodeIgniters AR functions. But at some situations it's simply easier to build query strings instead.

In your case:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
SELECT channel_id, SUM(times) AS sum
FROM channel
GROUP BY channel_id
ORDER BY sum DESC
");
```

---

You can also escape most values through db->query()!

```
$this->db->query("
SELECT name
FROM table_name
WHERE id = ?
", array(1));
```

Comment: And could you tell me what this query should be? My querying skills are not that good. I have never used the SUM before.

Comment: What column from which table do you wish to SUM()?

Comment: I want the channels to be ordered by the sums of their "times", as in the image above, the first shoud be channel = 21 because times = ( 117 + 1 ) is the highest

Comment: I've added what you might be after. If you need more columns then channel_id, simply add them per `,` after SELECT.

Comment: kk i solved it, Thx! `$query = $this->db->query("
   SELECT *, SUM(views.times) AS sum
   FROM channel
   RIGHT JOIN video
   ON channel.channel_id = video.channel_id
   LEFT JOIN user
   ON channel.user_id = user.user_id
   LEFT JOIN views
   ON channel.channel_id = views.channel_id
   GROUP BY channel.channel_name
   ORDER BY sum DESC
   ");`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as simple as `$this->db->order_by("channel_id", "desc");`? this orders the results by channel_id in descending order.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted me, i need them to order on the total sum of the numbers in the row "times" for each channel. so the first would then be channel = 21 because times = ( 117 + 1 ) is the higest number, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table displayed in your question is called times_table, and has a key of user_id, channel_id, you can use the following code to join the times_table into your query so the "times" column is available to sort by.

```
$this->db->join("times_table", "times.user_id=channel.user_id, times.channel_id=channel.channel_id", "left");
// You've already grouped by channel_name, so grouping by channel_id is probably not necessary.
$this->db->order_by("SUM(times_table.times) DESC");
```

N.B. I just guessed the name of your displayed table is times_table.